# Custom UITableViewCell - UILabel not aligned properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, alignment, uilabel

I am creating a custom `UITableViewCell` using the Storyboard editor.  I've got several components in this cell, but the biggest is a `UILabel` that is displayed at the top.  This label should be left-aligned, however I'm finding that when I run the app in the simulator to test, the text is centered.  I've tried specifying the alignment manually, but it always centers itself.

Is there something I need to do to get this working properly in a custom UITableViewCell?  I've never encountered anything like this before.

Comment: Make sure you didn't use a property name that conflicts with another UI element in UITableViewCell as the parent will probably modify it

Comment: Yes, I did confirm that this was not the case.  It's a unique property name.

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the cell implementation?

Comment: It's empty.  I subclassed it and added a UILabel property, but there is no custom implementation code to speak of yet.

Comment: Try using Debug->Color Render layers in the simulator to see if your text is actually centered, or the UILabel moved. Try removing the outlet if any, to prevent anything from tampering with it and see if it helps diagnose.

Comment: Using the colored layers, it appears as though the UILabel is actually moved to the center of the UITableViewCell, even though in the Storyboard editor its left edge is along the left edge of the cell.  What would cause this?  How do I correct it?

Comment: Make sure you added proper constraints to the label (or autoresizing masks). Anchor it to at least left and top and leave the other 2 sides free.

Comment: That was it!  Add this as an answer and I'll be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Debug->Color Render layers in the simulator to see if your text is actually centered, or the UILabel moved. Try removing the outlet if any, to prevent anything from tampering with it and see if it helps diagnose.
If the colored layer is offset, make sure you added proper constraints to the label (or autoresizing masks). Anchor it to at least left and top and leave the other 2 sides free.